# Animal detection using neural network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

When i run the last part to train model, i am not able to it is getting Intrupted Check the image for the error. As you see i want to detect whether i am able to train my model to detect the animal e.g. between Cat and Dog. [Dataset.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11T76B8UkTg9lU-sPhPlWqn6MOVhQ-FjS)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

# Initiallising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

#Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

# Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Full connection 
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss= 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                  shear_range = 0.2,
                                  zoom_range = 0.2,
                                  horizontal_flip = True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"D:\Neural Network\Neural Network Full Course-20240203T042209Z-001\Neural Network Full Course - Copy\Neural Network\training_set",
                                                target_size= (64,64),
                                                batch_size = 32,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"D:\Neural Network\Neural Network Full Course-20240203T042209Z-001\Neural Network Full Course - Copy\Neural Network\test_set",
                                                target_size= (64,64),
                                                batch_size = 32,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')

classifier.fit(training_set,
               steps_per_epoch=700,
               epochs=10,
               validation_data=test_set,
               validation_steps=10)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                  shear_range = 0.2,
                                  zoom_range = 0.2,
                                  horizontal_flip = True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"D:\Neural Network\Neural Network Full Course-20240203T042209Z-001\Neural Network Full Course - Copy\Neural Network\training_set",
                                                target_size= (64,64),
                                                batch_size = 32,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(r"D:\Neural Network\Neural Network Full Course-20240203T042209Z-001\Neural Network Full Course - Copy\Neural Network\test_set",
                                                target_size= (64,64),
                                                batch_size = 32,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')

##### Here i am getting error
classifier.fit(training_set,
               steps_per_epoch=700,
               epochs=10,
               validation_data=test_set,
               validation_steps=10)
```

Error:

[image: Image showing error]

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the error message: "Make sure your dataset can generate at least 7000 batches". Read the whole thing carefully — it is trying to help you.

[The Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) says this about the `steps_per_epoch` argument:

> If `x` is a `tf.data.Dataset` [it is], and `steps_per_epoch` is `None`, the epoch will run until the input dataset is exhausted.

That's what you want. So let `steps_per_epoch` be `None` by omitting it from the call to `.fit()`.

Comment: In my training data set, I have a total of 8000 images in 2 separate folders (Cats & dogs).  I have applied steps_per_epoch  = None. It Ran till 250/250 [===] - 306s 1s/step - loss: 0.6736 - accuracy: 0.5838 - val_loss: 0.6553 - val_accuracy: 0.5625.